# Expanding div which children position is absolute

Tags: css

Is there any option to prevent parent element be overflowed by children element when children element position is absolute and hight of children is higher than parent? I don't want to hide overflowing part by `overflow: hidden`, I want to force parent `div.alert` height to be not lower than its children. As you can see I am using `position:absolute` and `transform:tranlateY(-50%)` to put the content of `div` in the middle independently of the content length. Unfortunately when content is higher than minimum height of parent it goes outside of parent.

```
<div class="alert">
    <span>
        text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    </span>
</div>
<div class="alert">
    <span>
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    </span>
</div>
<div class="alert">
    <span>
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    background: #000;
}
.alert{
    position: relative;
    margin: 35px 5px;
    background: #4679BD;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    min-height: 40px;
}
span{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rnq046wg/1/)**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolute positioning is used for **exactly the opposite** of what you're trying to achieve. You never clarified whether it has to be and why does it need to be absolute.

You can easily achieve the same effect using padding on the inside element:

```css
body{
    background: #000;
}
.alert{
    position: relative;
    margin: 35px 5px;
    background: #4679BD;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    min-height: 40px;
}
span{
    padding: 12px 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">
    <span>
        text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    </span>
</div>
<div class="alert">
    <span>
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    </span>
</div>
<div class="alert">
    <span>
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    </span>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rnq046wg/4/

---

### Using the flex approach (be careful with older browsers):

```css
body{
    background: #000;
}
.alert{
    position: relative;
    margin: 35px 5px;
    background: #4679BD;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    min-height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
span{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">
    <span>
        text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    </span>
</div>
<div class="alert">
    <span>
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    </span>
</div>
<div class="alert">
    <span>
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: The example is simplified to represent the problem I am facing. What if I don't want to have that large padding when I have more than one line of the text?

Comment: I see, so the problem is to have it vertically centered inside an element with min-height when the child's height is way lower than the parent's?

Comment: Yes exactly, I thing I'll go in modified @simon solution with table layout and vertical-align, which I tried to avoid

Comment: Yeah, that's a bad approach... let me try something with the flex layout.

Comment: Got it: http://jsfiddle.net/rnq046wg/5/ No padding, it relies only on min-height of the parent now.

Comment: I have no idea why I didn't try flexboxes, big thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to deal with this because `position: absolute;` is intended to "go out" from the parent's model.

What you can do to solve your problem is using another approach to vertically center:

```
.alert{
    margin: 35px 5px;
    background: #4679BD;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    min-height: 40px;

    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
span{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rnq046wg/2/)

Answer (score 1):

If it a static text that not changed from time to time then give the `min-height` more space to contain the text.

Answer (score 1):

Assign fix `padding: 20px 0;` it will always populate content in middle, instead of using absolute position and all other junk.